# Function checking if element exists in list

Tags: arrays, function, loops

Here is what I have: It is working but it is printing out the answer for each item in my array. I only want it to determine if the item exists or does not and display one answer. Not sure where to fix this.

```
 function elementOccurs (item, list){

   for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(item == list[i]){
      console.log("Item exists");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Item does not exist");
    }
  }
}
elementOccurs("yo",["hello", "hey", "yo"]);
```

Comment: I think it's time to accept solutions from your previous posts. Zero solution acceptance record gives me a feeling you are taking answers for granted here.

Comment: @user3437460 yes you are correct. I have also posted a solution but no response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag variable, say `exist` that will determine if the value exist in array or not. You can use `break` keyword in your `for` loop if the match is found to minimise unnecessary loop.

```js
function elementOccurs (item, list){
 var exist = false;
 for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(item == list[i]){
      exist = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(exist){
    console.log("Item exists");
  } else {
     console.log("Item does not exist");
  }
}
elementOccurs("yo",["hello", "hey", "yo"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function elementOccurs (item, list){
   for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(item == list[i]){
        console.log("state is found");
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

var status = elementOccurs(yourItem,list)
```